# How to group tiles in the startmenu on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

Before downvoting, please read the post.

I'm using Windows 10 v1803, and I noticed by accident that you can group tiles to a folder.

I have tiles, set their size to small, and then I dragged one ontop of the other and it formed a nice group. Grouped, they are very tiny, but you click on them to unfold them similar as how it is done in iOS mobile.

Now, you think I figured it out as you can read above on how to do it, but when I tried to do it a second time, instead of grouping, it just pushes the other icon aside and it won't group.

Eventually after crazy mouse movements I got it to keep one icon on its size, changing the border to a bigger border indicating it would group and the other icon could hover it. Dropping it did indeed create the group.

So I tried it once more, and again, I just could not get it to group. Eventually after lots of wiggling, it was allowing the group again. I must be doing something wrong because I don't think: try until you have luck, is the method Microsoft intended.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

[image]

So, TL;DR: What is the correct way to group tiles in the Windows 10 Start Menu?

Comment: In my experiment, I was able to group actual applications, without any issue.  What worked for me was aiming for the corner of an icon instead of the sides nudged the icon over.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried that too, but doesn't work. But what I found out is that it is really easy to do with bigger icons, just not with the smallest ones. I do see that you can right click a new tile group and make it smaller, so you could make the icons big first, group them, then make it small again. also a quick left and right motion so they swap first then move back seems to be somewhat reliable to get it to group. I wonder if this is a bug in the code that I'm facing.

Comment: What also worked for me was to make one icon larger then the other.  Perhaps I have a more senistive mouse, but I didn't have that much trouble, creating the grouped tiles as you seem to have.  Difficult to say "what I did" because it's entirely mouse movements.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that size is an issue. Its like the smallest version has a very precise area where it sets the mode to grouping. Anyway, @Ramhound, feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: "Before downvoting, please read the post."  OK, I read the post.  Am I supposed to downvote now?   :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 lol. I prefer not, but if you still feel you should, then go ahead. Please leave a comment as to why though... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem is and what the actual solution is. It all appears to be in how quickly you move the mouse cursor.

If you drag and drop one icon over another at a slow speed, it will move the icon and make them switch places. If you drag and drop it as quickly as you can to the center of the icon you want to group with, it will reliably make a folder of the two icons.

In the past, I was bordering the slow and quick speeds so it would sometimes do the quick movement and thus group, and most of the time be to slow and just shuffle the icons around.

So to reliably group, drag the icon and move it as quickly as you can ontop of the icon you want to group with. If the distance is big, consider moving the icons next to eachother first then move it quickly into the icon you want to group with and voila.

I am currently on Windows 10 v1909, so it is well possible this behavior has changed since I used v1803 and that this technique didn't used to work.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are describing is called Start Menu Folders.
It was added around March 2017 with the Windows 10 Creators Update.

Creating a folder involves some mouse acrobatics, as it's easy to just
move the tile instead.
You should move your cursor slowly, until you see the tile you’re dragging hovering
over the target tile, and only then release it, creating a new folder
that contains them both.

[image]

Once the folder is created, click it to expand,
and click any tile inside to launch the app.
Click the arrow above the folder to collapse it again.

[image]

A nice write-up on this and other customization features can be found in
[10 Ways to Customize the Windows 10 Start Menu](https://www.howtogeek.com/197836/8-ways-to-customize-the-windows-10-start-menu/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still does not explain why it doesn't work reliably on small icons.

Comment: Perhaps you should move the cursor slowly until you reach the right spot. Implementation questions should really be addressed to Microsoft.

Comment: I tried everything from moving slow, to moving corners, when the icon is small it doesn't seem to work reliably. but making the icon bigger then doing it, then restoring it seems to work, which is what I also mentioned to @Ramhound, as I found out after his commenting.

Comment: The documentation says to hover over the center of the target tile, but it's not easy for a small tile.

Comment: Sorry, I generally do not click on links in an answer to read up on it, because at some point that link could become invalid, and if an answer needs info from a link, then the answer isn't up to par with SuperUser.

Comment: No problem, as long as the link lasts it might be useful for the curious. Just to remark that with the Wayback Machine most links are not lost.

Comment: @LPChip Have you tried dropping the tile into the folder as medium and then changing it to small?

Comment: @TrippKinetics I had similar problems with medium sized icons although it worked more reliably there. But I actually finally figured out what the problem is. Its all in how fast you drag the icon on top of another. Too slow and it will move them around. Fast enough, and they group.

Answer (score 1):

If the drag target is on its smallest size, it's hard to make it work. Make the target a bigger size, then drag everything in, then size it back down.